# Prevent the use of flash Event.DEACTIVATE in Chrome

Tags: javascript, flash, events, google-chrome-extension

I want to write an Google Chrome extension to prevent a specific webpage to react on blur events.

I know how to do it for the javascript part :  I inject some javascript in the page at runtime:"document_start" in order to overload the addEventListener method with my own function.

The problem is with flash parts on the page. Theses can use `addEventListener(flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE,deactivate_method_in_as3);`

Of course I'd like to prevent the method call

So I have several questions :

- Is it possible to set a security parameter somewhere to disallow Chrome to transmit focus related events to the application ?
- Is it possible to modify 'on the fly' the swf file to remove or overide this handler (of course I have no control on that swf).
- I also started to use the `chrome.debugger.*` and `chrome.windows.*`  APIs because they can intercept events early. In that case I have a annoying message saying "tab is debugged by ..."
- The swf has a similar handler for `flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE` so I can try to use it. But how to trigger it when the page is not focused ? (I tried to call `focus()` on it but it doesnt seems to work.
- Any other idea welcome :)

Thanks for reading